# error: called object is not a function or function pointer

Tags: c

I have the following code:

```
  z=x-~y-1;
    printf("%d",z);
  z=(x^y)+2(x&y);
    printf("%d",z);
  z=(x|y)+(x&y);
    printf("%d",z);
  z=2(x|y)-(x^y);
    printf("%d",z);
```

I get this error message:

```
10:11: error: called object is not a function or function pointer 
z=(x^y)+2(x&y); 
        ^
```

The language is C. Why did this happen?

Comment: What is `2(x&y)` supposed to do?

Comment: change to `2*(x&y)`

Comment: Oh Thx a lot!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for what the error means: `2(x&y)` tells the compiler to call the function `2`, passing `x&y` as an argument (just like `printf("hi")` means "*call `printf` and pass `"hi"` as an argument*").

But `2` isn't a function, so you get a type error. Syntactically speaking, whenever you have a value followed by `(`, that's a function call.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
z=(x^y)+2(x&y);
```

to

```
z=(x^y)+2*(x&y);
```

and

```
z=2(x|y)-(x^y);
```

to

```
z=2*(x|y)-(x^y);
```

You need the multiplication operator if multiplication is what you intended.